# Algorithmically generating a drop shadow?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics

For my game, I need to be able to generate drop shadows. The kind that only span the bottom right. Like this (neglect the blue square):

[image]

Given a 2D array of RGBA pixels, how could I generate a drop shadow bitmap?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is done by a [Gausian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) of a black square. It also can be done with every other shape.

Comment: Don't forget to perform the Gaussian blur on **linear** values, and to convert them back to **gamma-compressed** values when you want to display them.  Very important for getting proper light blending!

Comment: Formula for linear->sRGB gamma: `(c <= 0.0031308f) ? (c * 12.92f) : (std::pow(c, 1.0f / 2.4f) * 1.055f - 0.055f)`

Answer (score 4):

A shadow is a black object of the same shape as the one casting the shadow, blurred and shifted. That's all there is to it.